# Can I save this ficus elastica (rubber tree)?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, ficus

This tree was so lush when I bought it! I took it home, repotted it, and put it in an indirect sunlit spot by the window that usually has light for at least 6 hours. There was no new growth but I wasn't too skeptical since winter was approaching. After a few months, it started dropping it's lower leaves. I took a break from watering, although I always checked my soil prior to watering anyways. It's summer now and the tree has lost almost ALL it's leaves in the past week!! One trunk is actually completely bare! Is there any way to save this poor plant? :([image]

Answer (score 1):

Two things: water and air flow. Check that your pot is never sitting in water, that the pot can freely drain away any excess water. Let the surface dry out and then add some water, enough to moisten the root ball. Recall that the thick shiny leaves will store water so they will be inflating and deflating according to water available. Leaves full and soil wet is a problem, as is leaves deflated and soil dry.

Does the window leak cool air into the room or cause the room temperature to drop below 60F at night?

Otherwise the terminal buds look good and healthy; give it time, gentle water and keep it cosy warm.